# Is there a way to declare cells as NaN in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, null, ascii, nan

I am making a VBA code to import txt files (ascii) and perform calculations based on data in these txt files.

These txt files will be written to specific columns. When one of these files is missing, I want to be able to fill those columns with something like NaN so I can still perform calculations but the result would be NaN. If the columns are empty, it will certainly come out with an error.

I tried xlErrNull but it shows a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: A simple `If` statement will do the trick: `If FileName = "" Then... Else... End If`. Add more detail, the relevant code, and some screenshots to get a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will add the string "NaN" in any blank cell of the used range:

```
Sub fillNaNInEmptyCells()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngE As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
  On Error Resume Next
   Set rngE = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not rngE Is Nothing Then
    rngE.value = "NaN"
  End If
End Sub
```

If you change your mind and want removing the string, use the next code:

```
Sub replaceNaN()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   sh.UsedRange.Replace "NaN", ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is generate a #NA for example:

```
Sub x()

   Range("A1:A1").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Sub
```

in this example if we do b1=a1*2 for instance it will return #NA whereas if a1 is populate with a number n b1 will return 2n.